# Changing from one file to another

Tags: command-line, files, directory

I'm told to go to `/home/jbander/Downloads`, so how do I do that, I assume you do it in terminal but what do you do next, I can get to home but that is it.

How do I go from one directory or file or whatever they are, to another and once I'm there what do I do to see what is in the download file. One more question if I want to change it from e.g. cow to e.g. duck how would I do that(they are just arbitrary names)

How do I get rid of cow and how do I put duck in it's place.

Answer (score 3):

To change directory you use the command **cd**

e.g `cd /home/jbander/Downloads`

To list the directory use the commmand **ls**

If you want to change name on a file you use

`mv oldFile newFile`

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to a directory using a filemanager from your desktop environment. To go to the Downloads directory, select `Places -> Downloads` from the menu in the upper left of your screen.